# Building a dependency graph in real time

Tags: dependency-management, circular-dependency, directed-acyclic-graphs

A component of my system basically needs to build a dependency graph based on user input; there's gotta be a common way / library for doing this, I'm just unable to determine what it is. Example below (names / classes changed to protect the innocent):

User asks if a recipe has a cherry flavor, a potato flavor, and / or a mint flavor. We have various paths for the dependencies of each flavor (cherry goes recipeID -> A -> B -> C -> true/false, mint goes recipeID -> A -> D -> true/false etc). The idea is that whatever data source is called in A should only be called once. For simple cases, it's easy to come up with a solution, but as things get added like multiple inputs for a step (e.g. a diamond dependency) or needing to do batch calls (recipeID 1 for cherry, recipeID 2 for mint, should make a batch call to A(1,2) ) things get a lot more complicated.

Comment: It's not clear to me why this has to be a graph and not just a (merged) list.

Comment: It is implicitly a directed graph (that should be acyclic). Say D requires B and C, both B and C require A, E might only require B. Once B is done E should immediately begin (assume all of these are asynchronous operations) and not wait for everything else to finish. Of course, a Topological sort could be done as this is a directed acyclic graph, and so they could be put in a list, but it is at its heart a graph.